# android smoothscrolltoposition scrolls to last item directly (BUG)

Tags: java, android, smooth-scrolling

I'm making an horizontal RecyclerView (with MATCH_PARENT width layouts) that should scroll automatically to next/previous item when user stop dragging between two items

I tried to this

```
recyclerView5.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
            int currentPosition = 0;
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                if (RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING != newState){
                    if(currentPosition > 0){
                        Log.i(TAG, "onScrollStateChanged: Right" + manager5.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() + 1 );
                        recyclerView5.smoothScrollToPosition(manager5.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() + 1);

                    }else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onScrollStateChanged: Left");
                        recyclerView5.smoothScrollToPosition(manager5.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() - 1);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                currentPosition = dx;
            }
        });
```

It do scroll, but scrolls directly to last item not the next item , and when scroll left it scroll to first item directly then the activity crashes throws
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid target position.
In logcat i see

```
Log.i(TAG, "onScrollStateChanged: Right" + manager5.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() + 1 );
```

returns

```
onScrollStateChanged: Right01
onScrollStateChanged: Right11
onScrollStateChanged: Right21
onScrollStateChanged: Right31
onScrollStateChanged: Right41
```

i think it should return 01 , 02 , 03 , 04
i don't know if that's correct or not , any help?